# inserting multiple row of medicine using jquery and php codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to add medicine one time one row inserting if i want to add click button than open next medicine entry field than fillup and insert next row if one time 5 medicine entry than 5 time insert in to database .but here only one time insert data in to database **checkbox is not working only accept first value**

**view page**

[image]

**i have need database**

```
name      quantity     days     take medician
----------------------------------------------
Amit       1            2        morning,evening
-----------------------------------------------
Amitabh    2            3        evening,night
-----------------------------------------------
Amitabh    3            4        afternoon,night
kumar 
gupta
```

**inserting curent database**

```
name      quantity     days     take medician
----------------------------------------------
Amit       1            2        morning
-----------------------------------------------
```

**html view page**

```
 <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($app_booking as $row){ ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="doctorname" id="doctorname" value="<?php echo $row["doctor_name"];?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="doctorid" name="doctorid" value="<?php echo $row["doctor_id"];?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="appid"  name="appid" value="<?php echo $row["appointment_id"];?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="uid" name="uid" value="<?php echo $row["user_id"];?>">
    <?php };?>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" required=""></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" required=""></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="days" id="days"  required=""></td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
             <label class="form-check-label">                                               
            <input class="form-check-input checkbox_value" type="checkbox" name="take_medicine[]" id="morning" value="Morning"> Morning
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input checkbox_value" type="checkbox" name="take_medicine[]" id="afternoon" value="Afternoon"> Afternoon
            </label>
            </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input checkbox_value" type="checkbox" name="take_medicine[]" id="evening" value="Evening"> Evening
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input checkbox_value" type="checkbox" name="take_medicine[]" value="Night" id="night"> Night
        </label>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="#"  name="add" id="btn1" value="Add" class="btn bg-success-light"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Item</a>
        </td>
        <button type="button" onclick="save_medical_records();" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn">Save</button>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**ajax code**

```
 function save_medical_records()
           {
               
               var doctorname           =   $("input[name='doctorname']").val();
               var doctorid             =   $("input[name='doctorid']").val();  
               var appid                =   $("input[name='appid']").val();
               var uid                  =   $("input[name='uid']").val();
               var name                 =   $("input[name='name']").val();             
               var quantity             =   $("input[name='quantity']").val();
               var days                 =   $("input[name='days']").val();
               
                
                const take_meds = $("[name='take_medicine[]']:checked").map(function() { return this.value}).get()
                 console.log(take_meds);
                
               
                   $.ajax({
                       url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>add-prescription",
                       data:"doctorname="+doctorname+"&doctorid="+doctorid+"&appid="+appid+"&uid="+uid+"&name="+name+"&quantity="+quantity+"&days="+days+"&take_meds="+take_meds,
                       //data: $("[name=doctorname]").serialize(),$("[name=doctorid]").serialize(),$("[name=appid]").serialize(),$("[name=uid]").serialize(),$("[name=name]").serialize(),$("[name=quantity]").serialize(),$("[name=days]").serialize(),$("[name=take_meds]").serialize(),
                       
                       
                       
                       type:"post",
                       success:function(response){ 
                           if(response==1)
                              
                              $("#msg").css("display","block"); 
                           
                       }
                       });
               }
```

**controllers**

```
public function add_prescription()
    {
        $result = $this->doctor_health_model->add_prescription();
        echo $result;

    }
```

**models**

```
public function add_prescription()
    {
        $db2 = $this->load->database('dpr',TRUE);
        $medicine       = $this->input->post('name');
        $uid            = $this->input->post('uid');
        $appid          = $this->input->post('appid');
        $doctor_id      = $this->input->post('doctorid');
        $doctor_name    = $this->input->post('doctorname');
        $quantity       = $this->input->post('quantity');
        $days           = $this->input->post('days');
        $take_medicine  = $this->input->post('take_medicine');  
        $today_date     = date("Y-m-d");
        
     $insert =$db2->query('INSERT INTO dpr_save_farmacytest (medicine,user_id,appointment_id,doctor_id,doctor_name,quantity,days,take_medicine_time,created_date) 
            VALUES ("'.$medicine.'","'.$uid.'","'.$appid.'","'.$doctor_id.'","'.$doctor_name.'","'.$quantity.'","'.$days.'","'.$take_medicine.'","'.$today_date.'")');
            //echo $db2->last_query();
            return $insert;

        }
    }
```

Comment: That is how jQuery works - this will return ONE value, from the FIRST of the elements with the same name `var take_medicine =   $("input[name='take_medicine[]']").val();`

Comment: As per the jQuery documentation for that method, `.val()` only takes the value from the first matched element in any set. So if `$("input[name='take_medicine[]']")` matches many checkboxes, `.val()` will only get the value from the first one. To be honest, instead of trying to extract all the data one-by-one from your form, why not just use jQuery's `serialize()` method to handle it automatically? https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: P.P.S. Your database is also denormalised - you shouldn't really be storing multiple values (e.g. `morning, night`) in a single field like that. Please read up on relational database design before continuing.

Comment: share edit code please sir

Comment: For this add_prescription() function, you could use Code Igniter's active record library. It will prevent these issues.

Have a read of this - its very simple and will benefit you, both for more secure code and for easier reading of the code:

https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#insert

Comment: ok sir for advice me thanku so much but today i have problem here so please share your valuable idea any? share

Comment: I quickly knocked you up an example of codeigniter active record here: https://pastebin.com/rpmzfuVf

Comment: data is not  inserting sir

Comment: Check spelling mistakes, I just knocked it up quickly, I could've spelled a fieldname wrong. created_date vs created_data for instance is wrong

Comment: yes i am allrady chaing sir but multiple row inserting not working

Comment: INSERT INTO `dpr_save_farmacytest` (`medicine`, `user_id`, `appointment`, `doctor_id`, `doctor_name`, `quantity`, `days`, `take_medicine_time`, `created_data`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2020-08-24')

Comment: one time inserting row next row not inserting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the SQL Injection issues, the problem storing multiple values in one table field etc, your immediate question is answered by:

That is how jQuery works - this will return ONE value, from the FIRST of the elements with the same name

```
var take_medicine =   $("input[name='take_medicine[]']").val();
```

You need to get each checked checkbox  - for example

```js
const take_meds = $("[name='take_medicine[]']:checked")
       .map(function() { return this.value}).get();
console.log(take_meds);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input checkbox_value" checked type="checkbox" name="take_medicine[]" id="morning" value="Morning"> Morning</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input checkbox_value" type="checkbox" name="take_medicine[]" id="afternoon" value="Afternoon"> Afternoon</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input checkbox_value" checked type="checkbox" name="take_medicine[]" id="evening" value="Evening"> Evening</label>
</div>
```

You could possibly have a simpler life if you use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

IF You have `<form id="myForm"` - you change the WHOLE AJAX code to

```js
$("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>add-prescription",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    type: "post",
    success: function(response) {
      if (response == 1) $("#msg").css("display", "block");
    },
    error: function(jxhr) {
      console.log("Error", jxhr)
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220387/discussion-on-answer-by-mplungjan-inserting-multiple-row-of-medicine-using-jquer).